# Is (at least) 28 days and a sheriff court order always required to evict a Scottish common law tenant?

Tags: common-law, tenancy-rules, eviction, scotland

The one guaranteed condition is that the tenant does not live with their landlord. Regardless of what the tenancy agreement says, is a court order always required to evict such a common law tenant?

Comment: When did the tenancy start? On or after 01/12/2017, or before?

Comment: It started After 1.12.2017.